# Add building/Appartment layout to pre defined polygon into google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3

I have requirement to draw building or apartments top view 2d/3d image to predefined polygon.
So,I will draw polygon and that all coordinates will be saved to database.
Next time when page load which contain Google map which draw same polygon with saved coordinates.

http://jsfiddle.net/FUUxz/

```
var map; // Global declaration of the map
            var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // Global declaration of the infowindow
            var lat_longs = new Array();
            var markers = new Array();
            var drawingManager;
            function initialize() {

                 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.9403762, -74.1318096);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                drawingControl: true,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                    drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
                },
                        polygonOptions: {editable:true,fillColor:'#ff0000',strokeColor:'#ff0000',strokeWeight:2}
            });
            drawingManager.setMap(map);

            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(event) {
                var newShape = event.overlay;
                newShape.type = event.type;
                if (event.type==google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
                        overlayClickListener(event.overlay);$('#polygon').val(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());drawingManager.setOptions({drawingMode:null,drawingControl:false});
                    }

            });
                var polygon_plan_0 = [
                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.9534555976547, -74.0871620178223)
                    ,
                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.9410084152192, -74.0948867797852)
                    ,
                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.9411380854622, -74.1165161132812)
                    ,
                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.9490474888751, -74.1221809387207)
                    ,
                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.955140973234, -74.124584197998)
                    ,
                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.9604561066844, -74.1153144836426)
                    ,
                    new google.maps.LatLng(40.9534555976547, -74.0871620178223)
                    ];
                    lat_longs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.9534555976547, -74.0871620178223));

                    lat_longs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.9410084152192, -74.0948867797852));

                    lat_longs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.9411380854622, -74.1165161132812));

                    lat_longs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.9490474888751, -74.1221809387207));

                    lat_longs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.955140973234, -74.124584197998));

                    lat_longs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.9604561066844, -74.1153144836426));

                    lat_longs.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40.9534555976547, -74.0871620178223));

            var polygon_0 = new google.maps.Polygon({
                path: polygon_plan_0,

                strokeColor: "#ff0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#ff0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                editable: true
            });

            polygon_0.setMap(map);


            google.maps.event.addListener(polygon_0, "mouseup", function(event) {
                overlayClickListener(event.overlay);$('#polygon').val(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());drawingManager.setOptions({drawingMode:null,drawingControl:false});
            });


            }


        function createMarker(markerOptions) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
            markers.push(marker);
            lat_longs.push(marker.getPosition());
            return marker;
        }

initialize();

function overlayClickListener(overlay) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, "mouseup", function(event){
        $('#polygon').val(overlay.getPath().getArray());
    });
}
```

Now,I have small/large image with same polygon shape.

How can I put that image to polygon and properly fit it into map.?

Comment: You'll have to explain this a little better.  You have an image.  What image?  Can you show it?  Images are always rectangles.  Do you mean the rest is transparent (png of gif ?)?

Comment: You can see image like [this](https://i.imgur.com/5Lbka7v.png) and it is not necessary that image is always rectangle.It is top 3d/2d top view of any building that i will fit in google map using coordinates